# CSS style override doesn't work on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile-browser

Here's my code in a css. It's overriding a style written in the HTML file. I don't have access to change the HTML.

```
body[style] {
    background-color: yellow !important ;
    background: solid;
}
```

Background changes to yellow just fine on desktop Chrome. Doesn't work on mobile Chrome for Safari on iphone.

```
<body bgcolor="#000000" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 900px;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please remove `bgcolor="#000000"` from your `body` element and everything will work fine.

Comment: I don't have access to the html. It's a website that has an option to reference to your own style sheet that you store locally. Thanks though!

Comment: since the background is assigned in the HTML element you cannot override it because browsers count the style on the direct elements as number one priority.

Comment: That make sense, but why does my code work on some browsers (specifically desktop) an not others (mobile)?

Comment: it is better to have a separate style for mobile devices. also, not everything is supported on mobiles.. depending on the browser you are using.. you might get different results. It will take you a long time to style something near perfection.. you better ignore those errors if you are a single programmer designing a full website.